# Let $L$ be a lattice. Is there a union closed family of subsets of $[n]$ ordered by inclusion that correspond to $L$.

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of subsets of $[n]$ that is closed under taking unions (including taking the union of the empty set which is the empty set).  Then $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq)$ is a lattice.  But is the converse true?  In other words, given any lattice is there a union closed family of subsets of $[n]$ (for some $n$) whose members obey the order of the lattice?

I looked at all the lattices with up to 6 points and haven't found a counter-example but I can't come up with any algorithm that would prove the statement.

P.S.  I do know that the converse is true for distributive lattices.  Also, I am only considering finite lattices.

Comment: Are you only considering finite lattices?

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  Here, all lattices are finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is true.

If $L$ is a lattice and $x\in L$, define $A_x = \{z\in L\;|\;z\not\geq x\}$. The function   $A\colon L\to {\mathcal P}(L)\colon x\mapsto A_x$ is a join-embedding of $(L,\vee)$ into $({\mathcal P}(L),\cup)$. The collection $\{A_x\;|\;x\in L\}$ is therefore a union-closed set of subsets of $L$  which, when ordered by inclusion, forms a lattice isomorphic to $L$.

Comment: And more generally, every poset can be embedded into a power-set lattice. The embedding can be made to preserve all existing joins or all existing meets, but not both, in general.